# create a matrix of subtractions in sql

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
id_nbr t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
  1111  10 20 30 40 50 40  
  2222  40 10 50 20 70 90
```

And I would like to build a function that for each id_nbr will return the max substraction and the time diffrence for that substraction - for example:

for id_nbr 1111 the max is 40 from t1 to t5 so the function will return 40 and 4 (5-1) in diffent cells.
for id_nbr 2222 the max is 60 from t2 to t5 so the function will return 60 and 3 (5-2) in diffrennt cells.

```
Output:
exec find_max_and_time (1111) 

max_diff time
  40      4
```

Any help creating such kind of function?

the function suggested here in a query:

Answer (score 0):

Here one possible solution via unpivot. The idea is to turn your six columns into rows, geth their rowindex which represents the time (according to your example) and then get min and max value of the corresponding columns. However, you should consider handling of duplicates: it might happen, that two columns have the same value and with this you can have multiple matching records for min and max.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  id_nbr INT
 ,t1 INT
 ,t2 INT
 ,t3 INT
 ,t4 INT
 ,t5 INT
 ,t6 INT
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1111,10,20,30,40,50,40), (2222,40,10,50,20,70,90);


DECLARE @SearchID INT = 2222;
DECLARE @TimeIdxFrom INT = 1;
DECLARE @TimeIdxTo INT = 5;

WITH cteBase AS(
  SELECT id_nbr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_nbr ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn, times
  FROM (
  SELECT id_nbr, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6
    FROM @t t) t
    UNPIVOT(
      times FOR cTime IN (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
    ) u
),
cteMinMax AS(
  SELECT id_nbr, MIN(times) MinTime, MAX(times) MaxTime
    FROM cteBase
    WHERE rn >= @TimeIdxFrom
      AND rn <= @TimeIdxTo
    GROUP BY id_nbr
)
SELECT  --*,
        cbMax.rn - cbMin.rn AS TimeSpan,
        cbMax.times - cbMin.times AS ValDiff
  FROM cteMinMax AS cmm
  JOIN cteBase AS cbMin ON cmm.id_nbr = cbMin.id_nbr AND cbMin.times = cmm.MinTime
  JOIN cteBase AS cbMax ON cmm.id_nbr = cbMax.id_nbr AND cbMax.times = cmm.MaxTime
  WHERE cbMax.id_nbr = @SearchID;
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL return all calculate values

```
CREATE TABLE  dbo.T 
(
    id_nbr  INT,
    t1  INT,
    t2  INT,
    t3  INT,
    t4  INT,
    t5  INT,
    t6  INT
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.T   (id_nbr, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
VALUES
(  1111,  10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 40  ),
(2222,  40, 10, 50, 20, 70, 90  )

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.find_max_and_time(@Id INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH Desce AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES a.id_nbr , b.*
    FROM dbo.T a
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 1, a.T1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, a.T2 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, a.T3 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, a.T4 UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, a.T5 UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, a.T6  
    ) as b(N,Val)
    WHERE id_nbr = @Id OR @Id IS NULL
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_nbr ORDER BY Val DESC)   
), Asce AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES a.id_nbr,b.*
    FROM dbo.T a
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 1, a.T1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, a.T2 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, a.T3 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, a.T4 UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, a.T5 UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, a.T6  
    ) as b(N,Val)   
    WHERE id_nbr = @Id OR @Id IS NULL
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_nbr ORDER BY Val ASC)    
)
SELECT 
    a.id_nbr, 
    a.Val - b.Val   as Val,
    a.N - b.N   as N
FROM 
    Desce a
INNER JOIN 
    Asce b
ON a.id_nbr = b.id_nbr

GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.find_max_and_time (1111)

DROP TABLE dbo.T 
DROP FUNCTION dbo.find_max_and_time
```

Comment: If I rap this a function or use this with a query i get diffrent results - how is it possibol?

Comment: on the data you specify?

Comment: No I generlize it to 19 't' (t1...t19) and this is the example:
2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,5,5
I a function I get 5,9
In a  query 5,6 and the correct answer is 5,6 (from t1 to t7 the max diffrence is 5)

Comment: ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_nbr ORDER BY Val DESC, N DESC) and ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_nbr ORDER BY Val ASC, N ASC)

Comment: it gives me now 5,16. I should find the min time for a specific diffrence. In this case in t=7 it was the value 7 for the first time, so 7-1 = 6